# associate object with element using .data

Tags: jquery

I have to associate object with each `ul` which is created dynamically. I have used `.data` but it is giving undefined when try to retrieve. [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tfwp3wn3/)

```js
var file= [
                {
                    "name": "jhon",
                    "email": "manager",
                    "image": "images/profile-pic.png",
                    "data":{"name":"mile","depend":["amit","rajesh","deepak"]}
                },
                {
                    "name": "mile",
                    "email": "manager",
                    "image": "images/profile-pic.png",
                    "data":{"name":"mike","depend":["amit","rajesh","deepak"]}
                },
                {
                    "name": "steave",
                    "email": "manager",
                    "image": "images/profile-pic.png",
                    "data":{"name":"steave","depend":["amit","rajesh","deepak"]}
                }
]


 var html=""
 $.each(file,function(i,val){
  html+= "<ul>"+"<li>"+val.name+"</li>"+"</ul>"
  $(html).data('obj',val.data)  
 })
 
 $('#check').append(html)


$(function(){ 
$('ul').click(function(){
 console.log($(this).data('obj'))
})

})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="check"></div>
```

Comment: Your problem is that you are not using jQuery object with which data is associated `$(html)` and creating html using string

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Following lines are buggy in your code

1. `html+= "<ul>"+"<li>"+val.name+"</li>"+"</ul>"` - This line of code is actually collecting all UL's (Names) in one variable.
2. `$(html).data('obj',val.data)` - In this line, you are trying to set 'obj' data of each UL, but you are using 'html' variable that is a collection of ULs. It will work if you had only ONE UL, but as the loop proceeds, the HTML variable will contain more than one UL and the jQuery won't know for what element you want to set 'obj' data.

So now, to simplify, I changed these two lines to

1. `var ul= $("<ul>"+"<li>"+val.name+"</li>"+"</ul>");` - in this line, variable 'ul' will store the current UL created in the loop. So that we can use it in next line individually.
2. `ul.data('obj',val.data);` - here we will set the Data 'obj' for the current created UL. That's it
3. `$('#check').append(ul);` - Now, right after creating UL and setting its 'obj' data, we will add it in the page.

Minor change :

from

```
var html=""
    $.each(file,function(i,val){
        html+= "<ul>"+"<li>"+val.name+"</li>"+"</ul>"
        $(html).data('obj',val.data)        
    })

    $('#check').append(html)
```

to

```
$.each(file,function(i,val){
            var ul= $("<ul>"+"<li>"+val.name+"</li>"+"</ul>");
            ul.data('obj',val.data);
            $('#check').append(ul);

        });
```

```js
var file= [
                {
                    "name": "jhon",
                    "email": "manager",
                    "image": "images/profile-pic.png",
                    "data":{"name":"mile","depend":["amit","rajesh","deepak"]}
                },
                {
                    "name": "mile",
                    "email": "manager",
                    "image": "images/profile-pic.png",
                    "data":{"name":"mike","depend":["amit","rajesh","deepak"]}
                },
                {
                    "name": "steave",
                    "email": "manager",
                    "image": "images/profile-pic.png",
                    "data":{"name":"steave","depend":["amit","rajesh","deepak"]}
                }
]


 
 $.each(file,function(i,val){
  var ul= $("<ul>"+"<li>"+val.name+"</li>"+"</ul>");
        ul.data('obj',val.data);
        $('#check').append(ul);
  
 });
 
 


$(function(){ 
$('ul').click(function(){
 console.log($(this).data('obj'))
})

})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="check"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks. Working fine. Can you explain me what was the problem

Comment: @amit : Sure, will explain in the answer. please give me 2 minutes.